# Android: connect to local Wifi and mobile data at the same time

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi, mobile-data

We have a setup with a local IP camera connected over Wifi. From this camera the video stream should be streamed with an Android device over the cellular data network.
In iOS there is a trick to have both networks available by assigning a static IP address to the camera Wifi ([iOS: Use WiFi and Mobile Data simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37138871/ios-use-wifi-and-mobile-data-simultaneously)). Is there something similar on Android? I have tried to set a static IP address and also the Android "Download booster" mode, but both without success.

Regards,

Comment: did you found a solution?

Comment: No. On some Android phones it works but on most it doesn't.